# How to retrieve Arabic record from database via stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample_sp
    (
    @StartCreateDate NVARCHAR(30)= NULL,
    @EndCreateDate NVARCHAR(30)= NULL,
    @Name NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @Offset INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10
)
As
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT * FROM sample_table
   WHERE
        (@StartCreateDate IS NULL OR [created_at] >= @StartCreateDate)
        AND
        (@EndCreateDate IS NULL OR [created_at] <= @EndCreateDate)
        AND
        (@NAME IS NULL OR [name] = @Name)
  ORDER BY id
  OFFSET (@Offset)*@PageSize ROWS
  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
END
```

And the command for execution is

```
EXEC sample_sp @Name = N'سلام'
```

I have defined `Name` as `NVARCHAR(255)` and also in the execution command I use **`N`** before the string value, but still nothing is retrieved. On the other hand, while I use
`SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE name = N'سلام'` I get the correct record.

I was wondering what is wrong with my stored procedure or even with my execution command?

Comment: Why are your **date** parameters defined as an `nvarchar`? There are multiple date and time data types in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for your hint.  I guess I should change them to datetime2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with this `OFFSET` calculation:

```
OFFSET (@Offset)*@PageSize ROWS
```

With the default values (offset 1, pagesize 10), the value will be 10 so no rows will be returned unless 11 rows or more qualify for the other criteria.

If you want to treat @Offset like a page number, subtract 1 for the offset calculation:

```
OFFSET (@Offset-1)*@PageSize ROWS
```

Additionally, consider using strongly typed datetime types for the parameters and columns in the table.